# make a basic calculator

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

So I am new to Java and to practice my skills I decided to make a basic calculator. So this is my code:

```
/*Basic calculator.*/
package calculator;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class no_gui {

public static void main(String[] args) {

System.out.println("What math operation do you want to do?");
System.out.println("1. Addition, 2. Subtraction, 3. Multipilcation, 4. Division");
System.out.println("Enter number to corresponding math operation.");

Scanner calc = new Scanner(System.in);
double choice = calc.nextDouble();
double add1, add2, addAnswer, sub1, sub2, subAnswer, mult1, mult2, multAnswer, div1,     div2, divAnswer;

if (choice == 1){
System.out.println("Addition");
System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
add1 = calc.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
add2 = calc.nextDouble();
addAnswer = add1 + add2;
System.out.println("Your answer is " + addAnswer);

if(choice == 2){
System.out.println("Subtraction");
System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
sub1 = calc.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
sub2 = calc.nextDouble();
subAnswer = sub1 + sub2;
System.out.println("Your answer is " + subAnswer);

if(choice == 3){
System.out.println("Multipilcation");
System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
mult1 = calc.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
mult2 = calc.nextDouble();
multAnswer = mult1 + mult2;
System.out.println("Your answer is " + multAnswer);

if(choice == 4){
System.out.println("Divsion");
System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
div1 = calc.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
div2 = calc.nextDouble();
divAnswer = div1 + div2;
System.out.println("Your answer is " + divAnswer);
}else{
System.out.println("Re-run to use again.");
}
}
} 
}
}
```

}

Every time I run it and choose addition it'll do what ever is inside the if statement. But when I try subtraction it just prints out 2 and terminates the program. It worked before but today it stopped. I even tried a different method of coding and it still doesn't work.

EDIT: Thanks to everyone who responded. My main issue was resolved. But I also have this issue with switch statements and I forgot to mention that in my main question. Do I have to space everything? Does that cause the problem?

Comment: See my answer, it has all the info you need.

Comment: You don't *have* to indent your code; but one of the big advantages of using auto-ident tools is that when you screw your brackets up you code will be indented based on what the brackets say to do; not what you intended them to do.  It's impossible to say without seeing your switch statement; but if it's not working I'd guess you screwed the brackets up there too.

Answer (score 3):

You have nested if clauses. Look at your code and think about it logically.

```
if (choice == 1) {
   //add 
   if (choice == 2) {
     //subtract
   } 

}
```

You will never enter subtract or any other option for that matter because the outer `choice == 1` will never be true. Use this structure instead.

```
if (choice == 1) {
   //add     
}else if (choice == 2) {
     //subtract
   }
```

Or better, use switch statment. An example is given below:

```
 int month = 8;
        String monthString;
        switch (month) {
            case 1:  monthString = "January";
                     break;
            case 2:  monthString = "February";
                     break;
            case 3:  monthString = "March";
                     break;
            case 4:  monthString = "April";
                     break;
            case 5:  monthString = "May";
                     break;
            case 6:  monthString = "June";
                     break;
            case 7:  monthString = "July";
                     break;
            case 8:  monthString = "August";
                     break;
            case 9:  monthString = "September";
                     break;
            case 10: monthString = "October";
                     break;
            case 11: monthString = "November";
                     break;
            case 12: monthString = "December";
                     break;
            default: monthString = "Invalid month";
                     break;
        }
```

Example source : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: +1 for suggetsging switch  here cuz it is more readable to me

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that your checks of `choice` are all nested:

```
if (choice == 1){
    // ...
    if(choice == 2){
        // ...
        if(choice == 3){
            // ...
            if(choice == 4){
                // ...
            }else{
                System.out.println("Re-run to use again.");
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

If `choice` is 1, then that block will be executed.  If it's not 1, then the blocks that should be executed are all unreachable.

Try re-arranging your program like this instead:

```
if (choice == 1){
    // ...
} else if(choice == 2){
    // ...
} else if(choice == 3){
    // ...
} else if(choice == 4){
    // ...
} else {
    System.out.println("Re-run to use again.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem would be self-evident if you clicked "format code" in your IDE...

You have (inappropriately) nested your `if` blocks, like this:

```
if (choice == 1) {
    // do addition
    if (choice == 2) {
        // etc
```

Clearly, if choice is anything other than 1, the corresponding if block(s) will never get entered.

Instead, make the `if` blocks siblings:

```
if (choice == 1) {
    // do addition
} else if (choice == 2) {
    // etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not closing your if blocks properly. you should:

```
    if (choice == 1) {
        System.out.println("Addition");
        System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
        add1 = calc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
        add2 = calc.nextDouble();
        addAnswer = add1 + add2;
        System.out.println("Your answer is " + addAnswer);
    } else if (choice == 2) {
        System.out.println("Subtraction");
        System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
        sub1 = calc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
        sub2 = calc.nextDouble();
        subAnswer = sub1 + sub2;
        System.out.println("Your answer is " + subAnswer);
    } else if (choice == 3) {
        System.out.println("Multipilcation");
        System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
        mult1 = calc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
        mult2 = calc.nextDouble();
        multAnswer = mult1 + mult2;
        System.out.println("Your answer is " + multAnswer);
    } else if (choice == 4) {
        System.out.println("Divsion");
        System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
        div1 = calc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
        div2 = calc.nextDouble();
        divAnswer = div1 + div2;
        System.out.println("Your answer is " + divAnswer);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Re-run to use again.");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better in this case to use a switch/case:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class no_gui {

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
Scanner calc = new Scanner(System.in);
//double choice = calc.nextDouble();
int choice = 0;
boolean getOut=false;
double add1, add2, addAnswer, sub1, sub2, subAnswer, mult1, mult2, multAnswer, div1,     div2, divAnswer;
while(!getOut)
{

    System.out.println("What math operation do you want to do?");
    System.out.println("1. Addition, 2. Subtraction, 3. Multipilcation, 4. Division, else: stop");
    System.out.println("Enter number to corresponding math operation:");
    choice = 0;
    choice = calc.nextInt();

    switch(choice)
    {
    case 1: 
        System.out.println("Addition");
        System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
        add1 = calc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
        add2 = calc.nextDouble();
        addAnswer = add1 + add2;
        System.out.println("Your answer is " + addAnswer);break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("Subtraction");
        System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
        sub1 = calc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
        sub2 = calc.nextDouble();
        subAnswer = sub1 - sub2;
        System.out.println("Your answer is " + subAnswer);break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("Multipilcation");
        System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
        mult1 = calc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
        mult2 = calc.nextDouble();
        multAnswer = mult1 + mult2;
        System.out.println("Your answer is " + multAnswer);break;
    case 4:
        System.out.println("Divsion");
        System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
        div1 = calc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
        div2 = calc.nextDouble();
        divAnswer = div1 + div2;
        System.out.println("Your answer is " + divAnswer);break;
    default:System.out.println("Good Bye");getOut = true;break;
    }

}
}}
```